# Oracle - Order by specific values first, then the rest

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I've got an Oracle 11g table with a column indicating statuses for a number of items. Is there any way to do a select where three specific flags are ordered first, and then the rest in alphabetical order?

Something similar to

```
SELECT ITEM, STATUS FROM FOO ORDER BY STATUS ('I', 'U', 'P') ASC
```

which would then list all items with status I, then U, then P, and then the remaining items last.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This works for all DB engines

```
SELECT ITEM, STATUS 
FROM FOO 
ORDER BY case when STATUS = 'I' then 1
              when STATUS = 'U' then 2
              when STATUS = 'P' then 3
              else 4
         end,
         status
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

Working for me..Check the demo:

```
create table FOO (ITEM varchar2(10), STATUS varchar2(10)) ;

SELECT ITEM, STATUS 
    FROM FOO 
    ORDER BY DECODE (STATUS,'I',1, 'U',2, 'P',3,4) ;
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT ITEM, STATUS 
        FROM FOO 
        ORDER BY DECODE (STATUS,'I',1, 'U',2, 'P',3,4) ;
  2    3  
no rows selected
```

How are you using it ??

Comment: For some reason this throws an error about a missing right parenthesis.

Comment: Its working for me..Seems something wrong your tried..Check demo\

Comment: I can confirm that this works; the asker seems to have butchered the syntax somehow.